# I want to play an audio of a ringing bell in alert while user is waiting

Tags: javascript, audio, switch-statement, alert, document.write

I'm completing a task using **switch statements**. (the task was to show menus in alert when we are calling mobile network companies like press 1 for call package and press 2 for internet packages, so I set case 5 for customer service representative ) while he/she is waiting, **I want to play audio like a ringing bell** that the call is connecting to our customer service representative, please wait. But that isn't working.

- I have tried using audio tag is html and using its id to `document.getElementById('audio').src = audio.mp3`
- I have also tried it in alert using **audio tag inside alert.**
- I have also tried audio tag inside `document.write(<audio autoplay controls><source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>);`

```
javascript switch statements

    case 5:

    var callCenter = alert('We are redirecting your call to our Customer 
                     Service Representative.\nPlease wait.');
    var tone = document.write("<audio autoplay controls><source src=tone.mp3 
               type=audio/mpeg></audio>")

    break;
```

When the user press 5 to talk to a customer service representative. I want the alert to ring a bell while he is waiting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it won't work this way.

**1.** As soon as an alert dialog is openend, the execution of the script is stopped until you confirm that alert dialog. That means the sound has to happen just before you open the dialog.

**2.** With `document.write("")` you're overwriting your whole html document with the text/html provided inside write()

**3.** Playback of audio files needs user interaction - e.g. you need to press a button.

Here's an example:

```js
var audio = new Audio('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Sound_Effect_-_Door_Bell.ogg');

function customerService()

{
  audio.play();
  alert('We are redirecting your call to our Customer Service Representative.\nPlease wait.');
}
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", customerService);
```

```html
<button id="button">
5
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. It worked. Have a great life.